# ODOO 8 : Why purchase receipt form doesn't have a "Pay Bill" button like supplier bill?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo

**What I'm trying to do :**

*I'm trying to reproduce the button "Pay Bill" of the "Supplier Bill"'s form in the "Purchase receipt"'s form.
For that, I inherit `account.voucher` to add a function `voucher_pay_customer`, which is inspired from `invoice_pay_customer`. I also replicated the view `account.voucher.receipt.dialog.form`.*

**Why ?**

*Because the accountant currently has to create a supplier payment from an other form, in which he search for the previously create Receipt in order to register the payment*

**The Problem :**

*I can't make the writeoff_amount change in the dialog form, while trying to have as little differences between my `onchange`s and thoses of the invoice, since I don't want to alter some behavior I'm not aware about.*

Since I'm new to the accounting module of Odoo, I'm struggling to understand the way it is developped. Hence my question : **Why purchase receipt's form doesn't already have a "Pay Bill" button like supplier bill's form ?** I hope that understanding the limits that were encountered during the development, or maybe simply the reason of this choice, if it is one, will help me to better understand the root of my problem, and correct it.